# Why does jQuery qTip2 plugin work in a fiddle but not on my bare webpage?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, qtip2

I encountered the following error while attempting to use the Jquery qtip plug-in:

Firefox 22.0 (Linux Version):

```
Error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]
Source File: http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
Line: 6
```

Chromium Version 28.0.1500.71 Compiled for Ubuntu 12.04:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined jquery.min.js:6
```

I just tried this on Google Chrome too, in Windows XP VM and got the same result.

The error does not occur initially, only when the event is triggered.

The expected behaviour is that a tooltip will appear within a second or so after the link on the page is clicked, with text supplied via ajax, which says, 'This text came from the server and...'. The tooltip is not appearing.

I've created a fresh page with only minimum elements required to replicate this error, which can be checked here: http://snowweb.net/pages/test.php.

This is the code:

```
<? header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.1.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" />

        <!-- /stylings -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.1.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
        <!-- /scripts -->

    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="../ajax/tt_hosting-enterprise.php" class="ajax_TT">
        Enterprise hosting</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(window).load(function() {
                $(".ajax_TT").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
                    var link = $(this).attr('href');
                    $.ajax({
                        url     : link,
                        cache   : false,
                        method  : 'post',
                        data    : {
                            html    : ""
                        }
                    }).done(function(html) {

                        $(this).qtip({
                            content : {
                                text : html
                            }
                        });
                        $(this).qtip('toggle', true);

                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The really odd thing though, is that my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xV9aF/14/) works.

Comment: Does the page gets interpreted? Remove the php header if not

Comment: Also jquery UI has tool tips too

Comment: I just removed the character encoding on the development environment and the issue remained. I think all pages ought to have the page encoding sent in the header though. As for 'UI'. If I don't get this working, I might look at it, although I'd rather get this working.

Comment: Your `<meta charset='utf-8'>` will do the job too

Comment: Your fiddle does not load the CSS, perhaps that is why it works? Is qTip2 compatible with JQ2? I get the same error when I load the qtip correctly http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5gF6k/

Comment: That's true. I just fixed that and now the fiddle doesn't work either. Yes, according to the documentation for qtip it does work with JQ2. I also get the same issue when using 1.9.1 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reference to $(this) is out of scope.

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5gF6k/)

I am fixing the scope with `var $this=$(this);`

```
$(function () {
    $(".ajax_TT").on("click",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // normalized for IE
        var $this=$(this);
        var link = $this.attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            cache: false,
            data: {
                html: "<p>Text echoed back to request</p>"
            },
            method: 'post'
        }).done(function (html) {
            $this.qtip({
                content: {
                    text: html
                },
                style: 'qtip-wiki',
                show: {
                  ready: true
                }    
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please see update - I fixed the scope so you can have more than one link

Comment: Thanks. I did too, but you're solution is better :-)